# Is it safe to mount one partition on many directories?

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb

Example:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 dir1
mount /dev/sdb1 dir2
touch dir1/file1
touch dir2/file2
```

I'm worried about the collision of writing data, which may result in some corruption of the filesystem.

I read through `man mount` and `man umount`, but nothing about this was found. Actually, `man umount` implies this(=mounting on many directories) can happen but doesn't refer to the safeness.

(I just tested the situation and, at this moment, no problem has happened.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount a file system as often as you want. This is what bind mounts (`mount --bind`) do anyway.

A block device (containing the file system) cannot be opened a second time, though. But a second mount does not open the block device again. The second mount is just a feature of the virtual file system (VFS). The block device does not notice that.